# $\mathscr{L}_{p_2}\subset\mathscr{L}_{p_1}$ or $\mathscr{L}_{p_2}=\mathscr{L}_{p_1}$

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory

**Theorem:** *Given a measure space $(X,\mathscr{A},\mu)$ so that $\mu(X)<\infty$ .If $1\leqslant p_1<p_2<\infty$ show that $\mathscr{L}_{p_2}\subset\mathscr{L}_{p_1}$,[image]*

With this proof one can agree that every function that belongs to $\mathscr{L}_{p_2}$ must belong to $\mathscr{L}_{p_1}$.

Why does the exercise states $\mathscr{L}_{p_2}\subset\mathscr{L}_{p_1}$ instead of $\mathscr{L}_{p_2}=\mathscr{L}_{p_1}$?

How do we know $\mathscr{L}_{p_2}\subset\mathscr{L}_{p_1}$ from the proof above?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What's the $\mathscr{L}_{p_2}$? Is it $L^{p_2}(X)$?

Comment: Yes it the same thing but with different notation. The book does not care about the different notation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exercise says that $\mathscr L_{p_2} \subset \mathscr L_{p_1}$ because, unless the measure space has full measure on some finite set, there are measurable functions in $\mathscr L_{p_1}$ not in $\mathscr L_{p_2}$. For instance, consider Lebesgue measure on $(0,1)$. The functions
$$f(x)=x^{-c}$$
is in $\mathscr L_{p}$ if and only if $p<1/c$. In particular, this is a witness to the fact that the $\mathscr L_p$ spaces are not equal for distinct $p$.

Comment: Could you please explain me the example. I am not understanding it. Why  $p<1/c$?

Comment: The $p$-norm of $f$ is $\int_0^1 x^{-pc}$. By usual calculus exercises, this only converges if $pc<1$.